# Volume of Generalized Tetrahedron in $R^n$

Tags: geometry, multivariable-calculus

I'm having difficulty finding the volume of a tetrahedron in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

> Find the volume of a generalized tetrahedron in $\mathbb{R}^n$ bounded by the coordinate hyperplanes and the hyperplane $x_1 + x_2 + ... + x_n = 1$

In two dimensions, we have $\int_0^1 1 - x_1 dx_1$.
In three dimensions, I got something like $\int_0^1 \int_0^{1-x_1} 1-x_2 dx_2dx_1$.

I am off to a good start? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: For a general dimension $n$, you should speak of a simplex.  A tetrahedron is a three dimensional solid.

Comment: My textbook called it a "generalized" tetrahedron. Perhaps that resolves this confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is fine, but the allowable range in $x_3$ is $1-x_1-x_2$, so that should be your integrand.  It is probably easier to define the $n$-volume of a $k$ sided simplex as $V_n(k)$ and recognize that $V_n(k)=\int_0^kV_{n-1}(x)dx$.  Now each integral is a single one.  If you do the first few, you will see a pattern emerge, which you can prove by induction.

Answer (score 1):

It is more accurate to write for two dimensions like this:

$$
\int_0^1 dx_1 \int_0^{x_1} dx_2
$$

For third dimension it will be:
$$
\int_0^1 dx_1 \int_0^{x_1} dx_2 \int_0^{x_2}dx_3
$$
So you can easily write the expression for higher dimensions. My advise is to write the domain bound by hyperplanes more carefully. Your way is too difficult for further integration I guess.